# Stop emacs asking if a theme is safe

Tags: themes

I set my theme with load-theme in a use-package macro loaded at startup. The theme has also been installed with use-package, from the repository.

At each start emacs asks me if I really want to load the theme in case it's not safe, how can I tell him to stop ?

Comment: It should also ask you if you want to have your choice remembered by emacs for future sessions, but it sounds like it does not ask you this, am I right? If it is not, I am not sure why. Try using `M-x load-theme` and selecting the theme you want to use, and see if it offers you the option to recognize it is safe in the future. I just tried installing a new theme and loading it this way, and it worked for me. The hash of the theme needs to be added to `custom-safe-themes` but I am not sure how to do this manually - probably you shouldn't.

Comment: If all else fails, you could add `(setq custom-safe-themes t)` to your init file before you load your theme. This will treat all themes as safe, which could be a risk in theory, but if you are only installing themes from trusted sources, I don't see any issue

Comment: When I `M-x load-theme` emacs doesn't ask me like if it is safe yet, but when I load it from a .el file at startup it still asks me if I want to run lisp code.
`(setq custom-safe-themes t)` works for me so I'll test new themes in a session before loading  them. Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Set the second argument of the `load-theme` function. From its docstring:

> If the theme is not considered safe by ‘custom-safe-themes’,
>   prompt the user for confirmation before loading it.  But if
>   optional arg NO-CONFIRM is non-nil, load the theme without
>   prompting.

For example:

```
(load-theme 'solarized-dark t)
```

will load the `solarized-dark` theme without asking.

Comment: Oh thank you that's the proper way !